# Sequentially apply files to DB in specific order using Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I receive a package from my manager in compressed format, and below file path structure would be there upon extracting the same. These files must be copied in a specific sequence to a Database.

```
--DDL
-----abc.sql
--Table
-----def.sql
--Function
-----ghi.sql
--Stored Procedure
-----jkl.sql
```

The requirement is such that contents of folder DDL must be applied first, then Table, then Functions and finally Stored Procedure.

Sometimes there would be only two folders like below

```
--Function
----abc.sql
--Stored Procedure
----jkl.sql
```

In such cases too, stored procedure must be applied at the end. The order cannot be changed irrespective of what folders are there in the extracted file.

How to achieve this in Python?

I have tried os.walk, but looks like it doesn't have what I am looking for though it walks over all directories.

Regards

PS: Based on @bruno desthuilliers suggestion, I have tried the below code snippet.

```
from os import walk
from argparse import ArgumentParser as parser

parse = parser()
parse.add_argument('-p', '--path', action='store', dest='path', help='mention the sql objects path')
args = parse.parse_args()

path = args.path

for(dir_path, dir_list, file_list) in walk(path):
    for dir_list in ('DDL', 'Table', 'Function', 'StoredProcedure', 'Trigger', 'DML'):
        if path(dir_list):
            for file_list in path(dir_list):
                print(file_list)
```

I know there is mistake but cannot identify where it is...I have got the below error.

```
C:\Users\Kris\eclipse-workspace\Utilities\Windows>python sequence.py --path "C:\MyCave\iso\DG\Int\Intest\dirtest"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "sequence.py", line 12, in <module>
    if path(dir_list):
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

Comment: Can you show us what you've tried so far? It sounds like you want to iterate over a known set of directories in a specific order; that sounds a lot like a `for` loop.

Comment: @larsks I have added what I have tried to the question

Comment: `path` is a string. You seem to be treating it like a function by calling `path(dir_list)`. What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: @larsks path is a command line argument (i am passing the path where sql objects are present).

Comment: ...and it's a string. What are you trying to accomplish with `if path(dir_list)`?

Comment: @larsks I am trying to say *if these sql object directories are there* kind of thing...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your latest error is happening because you are creating a string variable named `path`:

```
path = args.path
```

But you are then attempting to use that as if it were a function:

```
if path(dir_list):
```

That doesn't make any sense, and that is the cause of the "TypeError: 'str' object is not callable" error.

---

What we're suggesting is that your outer loop should be a simple `for` loop that iterates over the names of your special directories in the correct order.  Something like:

```
for dirname in ('DDL', 'Table', 'Function', 'StoredProcedure', 'Trigger', 'DML'):
   ...
```

For each directory, you need to:

1. Check if it exists
2. Iterate over the files in that directory

That's going to look something like this:

```
import os
import argparse

parse = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parse.add_argument('-p', '--path', action='store', dest='path', help='mention the sql objects path')
args = parse.parse_args()

for dirname in ('DDL', 'Table', 'Function', 'StoredProcedure', 'Trigger', 'DML'):
  dirpath = os.path.join(args.path, dirname)
  if os.path.isdir(dirpath):
    for fname in os.listdir(dirpath):
      fpath = os.path.join(dirpath, fname)
      print('Do something with {}'.format(fpath))
```

Some things to note about the above code:

- There's really no reason to set `path = args.path`. Just keep calling it `args.path`.
- I'm using `os.listdir` instead of `os.walk`, assuming that your directories just contain `.sql` files, rather than additional nested directories.
- If you want to test if something is a directory, use `os.path.isdir`.

Answer (score 0):

Simple algorithmic question, nothing python specific here. And the answer is **very** simple and obvious (python-like pseudocode version):

```
for dirname in ("DDL", "Table", "Functions", "Stored Procedure"):
    if your_archive_contains(dirname):
        for sqlfile in your_archive_list_sql_files_in(dirname):
            apply_to_your_database(sqlfile)
```

Now you just have to properly implement it ;-)

Comment: I have added code snippet based on your suggestion in the question section. Please check :)